# Calculating previous day sum and lag function not working properly

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using lag function to get previous date but not getting desired result

```
Client  Account#    Trade Date  Amount  Prev Txn Date   Output Received Sum
    A     1         1/1/2016    10       -                                0 
    A     1         1/1/2016    20       -               1/1/2016         0
    A     1         1/1/2016    30       -               1/1/2016         0   
    A     1         1/4/2017    40       1/1/2016        1/1/2016        60  
    A     1         1/4/2017    50       1/1/2016        1/4/2017        60
```

How can I get previous txn date column instead of output received column. I am using lag function 
Also I need to calculate the sum of transactions occured before the transaction date.
I used the following code

```
select 
  a.*, 
  lag(trade_date) over (partition by client, account# order by trade_date) next_txn_date_2 
from tmp_burst_activity_4
```

Comment: for the lag part I wrote the following code but the output received was not correct  select a.*, lag(trade_date) over ( partition BY client,account#order by
 trade_date ) as next_txn_date_2 from tmp_burst_activity_4

Comment: What's the lag function code you have used?

Comment: Question is not clear. Please provide the desired output and what you get instead.

Comment: Output received column is the output I got. I need to get Previous transaction date as output

Comment: Please edit your question to make it very clear what you base data is, which additional columns you want to calculate, and what the rules are. It isn't clear what the data you've shown represents, or how it relates to the query attempt you added, or what you've described. Also show the output you need to see. If you include any current calculated output, make sure you say *why* that isn't correct too.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the `LAG()` function is not working properly? I find that exceptionally hard to believe - it has always worked properly for me. You may want to consider that perhaps **you** are not using it properly?

Comment: For previous day wouldn't you want `LEAD(TRADE_DATE)` instead of `LAG()`? Or else `ORDER BY TRADE_DATE DESC`?

Answer (score 0):

First get the total amount per day,client and account and use `lag` after that and finally join this result to the original table.

```
select t.account,t.client,t.trade_dt,t.amount,s.prev_trade_date,s.prev_total
from tbl t
join (select account,client,trade_dt
      ,lag(trade_dt) over(partition by account,client order by trade_dt) as prev_trade_date
      ,lag(total) over(partition by account,client order by trade_dt) as prev_total
      from (select account,client,trade_dt,sum(amount) as total
            from tbl
            group by account,client,trade_dt
           ) t
     ) s on s.account=t.account and s.client=t.client and s.trade_dt=t.trade_dt
```